# Your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: 8, installation, composer, acquia-dev-desktop

We use the following for our local development environment. When we run `composer require 'drupal/module_name:^1.1'`, we get the following error message. We have doubled checked that all settings for `Acquia Dev Desktop` are set to `php7.1.11`, but still getting this message.

Error Message:

> Problem 1
>
> ```
> - symfony/browser-kit v4.1.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - symfony/browser-kit v4.1.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - symfony/browser-kit v4.1.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Installation request for symfony/browser-kit (locked at v4.1.7) -> satisfiable by symfony/browser-kit[v4.1.7].
> ```

Local Development environment:

1. [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://dev.acquia.com/downloads)
2. `Dev Desktop` set to php `v7.1.1`
3. Using `git bash` by navigating to `~/Sites/local-dev/dev`

Running `php --version` in the `~/Sites/local-dev/dev` (which is one level above `docroot`) we get `php 5.6.32`

Why am I still getting the `your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement` even though `Acquia Dev Desktop` is set to `phpv7.1.11`?

Comment: The problem is the version of PHP used in your shell. Are you launching the shell using Acquia Dev Desktop, by clicking on the terminal icon (which is located on the same height as "Local code")?

Comment: @Watergate no, i have been using `git bash` in the `~/Sites/local-dev/dev` directory

Comment: Then you have to update the PHP version used by Git BASH, or instruct Git BASH to use the correct PHP version located in the DevDesktop folder.

Comment: I assume your using Windows, in that case I can recommend using WSL. WSL provides a full Bash shell based on Ubuntu. I'm using it myself for all command line functionality, such as git (flow), composer, drush, etc. You can use apt-get to install such as php, mysql, etc. To make it fully work with Drupal, the only thing you need to do is to enter the database credentials in the settings.php which you can find in the `DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR` (typically: ['driver' => 'mysql', 'database' => '<db-name>', 'username' => 'drupaluser', 'password' => '', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 33067].

Comment: I really can't stress enough using a better VM setup, one that you can ssh into the box and avoid these host level issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, I found out that I had an outdated composer so I did the following steps and now composer is seeing the correct php version.

Previous version of composer was `1.6.3` and php version `5.6.32`

Steps:

1. ran `composer self-update`
2. ran `composer diagnose` and observed the following below

> Checking platform settings: OK
>
> Checking git settings: OK
>
> Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
>
> Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
>
> Checking github.com oauth access: OK
>
> Checking disk free space: OK
>
> Checking pubkeys: Tags Public Key Fingerprint: xxxxx
>
> Dev Public Key Fingerprint: xxxxx
>
> OK Checking composer version: OK
>
> Composer version: 1.8.0
>
> PHP version: 7.1.11
>
> PHP binary path: C:\path\to\devdesktop\php7_1\php.exe